# Java String.split(regex) not working

Tags: java, string

I want to split a string each time there's a `|` in it, but the `split` method only accepts a regex. The regex `|` splits the string after each letter, which is not what I want.
Using `\u007C` does the same thing too.

I tried using `\|`, but that just gives me: `Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are  \b  \t  \n  \f  \r  \"  \'  \\ )`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to do something like this:

```
\\|
```

The reason is that in regular expression in order for "|" to be considered as "|" and not as a regex operator you need the "\". But in java you can't just write "\" in a string because that's a save operator in a string. So you have to do `\\`. Hope that explains it.

Answer (score 2):

Escape the backslash.  You are in a Java string, and it should contain a literal backslash.

```
"\\|"
```

Answer (score 2):

Works for me:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Testing {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        String word= "abc|def";
        String[] splitted = word.split("\\|");
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(splitted)); /* prints: [abc, def] */
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

An alternate suggestion is to use `Pattern.quote("|")`.